# Add a local printer port in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, printing, printers

**Description:** I need to change a local printer port of an exiting printer in any client where the local ports are pointing the old server.

**Exmaple:**
If I have my `PRINTER` with local port `\\OLDSERVER\PRINTER`, I need to change it's local port to `\\NEWSERVER\PRINTER`

**Here my code**: it seems that the Add-PrinterPort can't manage backslash as name of the local port: if I use a simple string without any backslash, it works.

```
$PrintersList = Get-Printer| where {$_.type -match ‘Local’} | Select-Object Name

foreach ($Printer in $PrintersList){
  
  $PrinterObject = Get-Printer $Printer.Name
  $PrinterObjectName = $PrinterObject.Name
  
  $CurrentPrinterPort = "\\sprnvivv03\$PrinterObjectName"

  if ($PrinterObject.PortName -eq $CurrentPrinterPort){
    
    echo $PrinterObject
    
    $NewPrinterPort = "\\sprnvicc01\$PrinterObjectName"

    Write-Host $NewPrinterPort
    
    Add-PrinterPort -Name $NewPrinterPort

    #Add-PrinterPort -Name $NewPrinterPort
    #Set-Printer -Name $Printer -PortName $NewPrinterPort
    #Remove-PrinterPort -Name $RealPrinterPort
    
    echo $PrinterObject
  }
  else{
    echo "NO"
  }
}
```

**Here the exception:**

```
    Add-PrinterPort : An error occurred while performing the specified operation.  See the error details for more information.
At line:16 char:5
+     Add-PrinterPort -Name $NewPrinterPort
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_PrinterPortTasks:ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_PrinterPortTasks) [Add-PrinterPort], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070043,Add-PrinterPort
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: If you first **Export** as Csv using `-Delimiter ';'`, and immediately after **Import** that same data _without_ specifying this delimiter, the import will go wrong because by default it expects a _comma_. Besides.. why export/import at all and not capture the results of the `Get-Printer` cmdlet in a variable straight away??